# Do I have to setup pod for every project?

Tags: cocoapods

I am trying to learn how to use `pods` and i am following [this](http://blogs.triffort.com/?p=309) tutorial, however i am stuck on point number 3, under the heading **How to setup POD for your Xcode project.** It's been a long time since it's showing `Setting up CocoaPods master repo` on the terminal, after going through some posts on SO, i checked my `Activity Monitor` and the process `git-remote-https` have consumed around 300 MB and is still in progress. I can't figure out what is consuming so much of data, also since i have navigated to the project in which i wish to use `pod`, is the pod setup being done for that particular project only ? What if i have to use pod in some other project, do i have to `setup pod` again, will it consume that much of data for that project too ? 
Sorry if these questions are noobish.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.

You only have to install Pod for one time.

Then in your other project, It's very simple. At first you need to create a file named `Podfile`, write something needed in it, like `pod 'CocoaAsyncSocket'`. after that, all you have to do is to run `pod install`